# Content Provider Exa

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Hi im going through Content Providers in Android.Im unable to get a exact code example.i googled it i couldnt find the easy and understandable code.please help me by providing some links thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

In this place you have all the information that you need about Content Providers:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

*A ContentProvider can be used internally in an application to access data. If the data should be shared with another application a ContentProvider allows this.*

[Content-providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

[Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

[Android Tutorial: Writing your own Content provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)

[ContentProvider User Demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/64.html)

[Android Content Providers](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iv-android-content-providers/)